# Como manipular arquivos docx utilizando o python?

Tags: python

Eu criei dois arquivos `docx` mas não consigo escrever neles(utilizando o python) porém eu consigo fazer isso com arquivos txt. A pergunta é eu poderia criar um arquivo `docx` e escrever nele usando um script python?

Comment: Sim, basta utilizar o padrão definido pelo DOCx. Arquivos textos são simples pois recebem textos crus. O DOCx provavelmente é um arquivo texto no formato XML com uma estrutura não tão simples que deve ser seguida para que os leitores entendam. Se utilizar esse padrão, irá funcionar normalmente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é um zip cujo corpo é delimitado por um xml. Não se esqueça que você pode por diversos arquivos embutidos, daí a necessidade de ser um formato contêiner, tipo o zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão é que documentos como .docx, o antigo .doc, ou o .odt do libreoffice são *ordens de grandeza* mais complexos do que um arquivo .txt normal. 
Apesar de ser fácil entender como eles funcionam (o .docx e .odt, não o .doc)- o comentário do Quesado na questão está correto - eles são arquivos complexos para se lidar. Ambos os arquivos são um container do tipo ".zip", com um ou mais arquivos do tipo ".xml" embutidos. (Podem ser produzidas versões de ambos os arquivos apenas como um .xml, sem serem um .zip, mas não é um formato muito utilizado - o libreoffice mesmo demorou para suportar .odt não zipado)

Em particular não é obrigação de nenhuma linguagem de programação ter ferramentas já inclusas para manipulação desses tipos de arquivos: esse tipo de suporte é propiciado por módulos terceiros. Felizmente o Python tem um eco-sistema de módulos que tem algumas ferramentas que podem manipular diretamente isso, e esses módulos são fáceis de instalar com a ferramenta  "pip".

Perceba que as duas tecnologias usadas pelo docx e odt *são* suportadas indiretamente pela biblioteca padrão do Python - há o módulo `zipfile` que permite extrair, atualizar e criar arquivos do tipo `zip`, e há o `xml.etree` que permite ler e escrever arquivos XML tratando as tags como "nós" apropriados. O problema é que a estrutura e o que vai dentro do arquivo XML em cada caso é complexo, independente de você poder escrever no mesmo ou não. Só para criar um programa que possa abrir corretamente o container .zip de um odt ou docx, e fazer o parse do xml interno, e poder atualizar isso e criar uma nova versão do docx ou odt tomaria a maior parte de um dia de um programador experiente e motivado.

Esses módulos para atualizar e criar arquivos do tipo já fazem o serviço sujo - mas atualizar o conteúdo desse tipo de arquivo continua sendo complicado: você vai ter que saber como criar o tipo de dado em Python que representa o tipo de dado que deseja inserir no arquivo (parágrafo, tabela, etc...), e como fazer para inserir esses dados no lugar editado, mas isso só depois de aprender a usar a biblioteca para ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Provavelmente o módulo ["python-docx"](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) vai permitir que você possa fazer o que quer, mas sugiro uma boa olhada na documentação do mesmo antes de tentar utiliza-lo.

Alternativamente, se você precisa criar texto com estilos diferentes, cores, etc... pode ser *Bem mais simples*  criar um documento HTML com uma folha de estilos adequada, e usar ou um comando de linha de comando, ou o `selenium` para executar um browser para ler, renderizar esse html e gerar uma saída em PDF. (ou o HTML com a folha de estilos pode ser lido diretamente pelo próprio MicrosoftWord ou LibreOffice). A docuemntação de HTML + CSS é muito mais fácil de ser consultada, tem milhares de vezes mais exemplos,  e de quebra você ainda pode usar uma das muitas ferramentas de template do Python, para escrerver o "esqueleto"  e forma geral dos documentos que seu programa precisa gerar, e criar apenas o "recheio" com os dados relevantes em código Python. Eu sugeriria usar o [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/), que é um pacote de template muito usado em programação Python para web.

Comment: Mas, se tenho um documento `docx`, como faço para acessar o zip file correspondente a esse documento? Já tinha ouvido falar que docx é baseado em xml, mas nunca sei como acesso esses arquivos xml.

Comment: No Windows, o sistema usa a extensão do arquivo de forma meio "obrigatória" para os aplicativos - é só renomear seu arquivo ".docx" para ".zip" e abrir com o app que você usa para ZIP normalmente.

No Linux e no Mac, é só abrir o arquivo no app de zip que você usa, não precisa nem renomear.